# Facebook error: Encountered an error while processing the request: 502 Error parsing server response. Got EOF while waiting for outstanding responses

Tags: iphone, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

Today I started receiving errors from Facebook when my app tries to post a message.

The app successfully authorised, Facebook message window pops up, everything looks fine (links, pics, description) , but when I press post. it times out with this message

Encountered an error while processing the request: 502 Error parsing server response. Got EOF while waiting for outstanding responses Please try resending your request. This is probably not a bug in proxygen. Based on experience, either intern or latest is temporarily down due to a SEV or push. Please check in e FYI or #e first. If the error persists through retries, or if you have good reason to suspect this is a bug in proxygen, please report the issue to ti-bugs@lists or #ti with the following debug information: 2012-05-20 22:24:40 slb010.02.snc5 1585267068836963531

**UPDATE: It is a Facebook issue. There is an opened and assigned bug report [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/411849912170144?browse=search_4fb9fb43db2468a28526107)** You can subscribe there to follow the process.

[image]

Comment: Somehow I don't think this an error from Facebook...

Comment: It sound like a hardware error, i'm just wondering whether my app does something which triggers it or something is down.

Comment: We're getting the same error here in an iOS app! any ideas?

Comment: No, I tried two of my old apps already in the app store. Same thing.

Comment: There is an open bug on Facebook http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/411849912170144?browse=search_4fb9f54699e702828147939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Facebook fixed the issue. My apps work fine.

If you still experience the same problem, you can check out the progress here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/411849912170144?browse=search_4fb9fb43db2468a28526107

If this issue comes up again check whether there is an already submitted bug here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ if there isn't submit one

Comment: I've experienced the error 'Got EOF while waiting for outstanding responses' today while logging into Facebook. (on Chrome)